# How to re-sign ipas on a Mac

Tags: ios, air

Is there a clear work-flow for signing, on a Mac, completed ipas generated in Adobe Animate on Windows?
Or, is there a way to sign AIR for iOS ipas on Windows with signing certificates made with the new Apple Intermediate Certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer in a recent discussion in the AIR Runtime Support Forum@Gamua:

https://github.com/Gamua/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/511#issuecomment-741844598